# Shopify - How to call specific metafield from multiple uploaded product

Tags: html, json, shopify, liquid

I created a "Product Reference" and "List of products" `metafield`. This allows me to add multiple products into the `metafield` that I made. What I'm trying to do is display images and titles of the products that I added but what I would like to do is able to access each of the products I added.
[image]

For example, I have added two products to my `metafield` section but I only want to display one of them on my product page.
[image]

The reason why I would like to access my products individually is I'm going to use bootstrap and I want to add each product picture individually to the divs I created.

Here's what my code looks like when I'm trying to call my `metafield`. (It brings both of the pictures)

```
   {% if product.metafields.my_fields.custom_img.value != blank  %}

    <h3>Recommended Products</h3>
    
    {% assign recommended_products = product.metafields.my_fields.custom_img.value %}
    {% for product in recommended_products  %}     
    
      <a href="{{ product.url }}">
        {{ product.featured_image | image_url: width: 400 | image_tag }}
        
      </a>
   
    {% endfor %}

   {% endif %}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't get the question. What is the problem with the code that you shared? Does it work?

Comment: The code is working but as you can see im adding a two different product into my metafield. What im trying to do is even theres a two added product i would like to show the picture of the first one or the second one instead of both showing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only the first the easiest way is to do

```
{% for product in recommended_products limit: 1  %}     
 <div> ... </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Or if you want to display a particular product

```
{% for product in recommended_products  %}     

  {% if product.title == "title"  %}
    <div> ... </div>    
    {% break %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to have more control over the for cylce liquid offers you the `forloop` object https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/for-loops

For example you could also do

```
{% for product in recommended_products  %}     
 <div>... </div>
 {% if forloop.index0 > 1 %}
    {% break %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

to display the first 2 products.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the metafield that you've created just like any list in liquid, for example, if you want to access the first product in the list you can do

```
{% assign first_product = product.metafields.my_fields.custom_img.value | first %}
```

Or you can access any specific product in the list like so:

```
{% comment % }Access second product {% endcomment %}
{% liquid
  assign second_product = product.metafields.my_fields.custom_img.value[1]
  if second_product != blank
    echo '<h1>second_product.title</h1>'
  endif
%}
```